# Python script hangs without throwing exception/error on Windows

Tags: python, powershell, taskscheduler

There isn't a particular point in the script where it hangs (I've seen it getting stuck at random points in the script), so checking the logs didn't yield much insight. It doesn't even throw an exception or an error. It just keeps running while stuck.

I'm basically calling this python script from a powershell file (which later gets called by Task scheduler).

```
$python = "C:\Python34\python.exe"

$python_path = "C:\Source\main.py"

cd (split-path $python_path)

while($true)
{
    & $python $python_path
}
```

Is there something I need to do to make sure it doesn't get stuck?

Comment: did you try add sleep inside while for few secs?

Comment: @Haranadh actually it's getting stuck even in the first iteration of the script.

Comment: @90abyss I know its been few years since you asked this, but did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You Will have to do your path strings like this `path ="c:\\test\\file"`
Because it ignorer the first backslash